# serving employees

Tags: meaning, word-usage, english-to-german, usage, meaning-in-context

Could you help me translate the following sentence?

> As the head of the department I am serving 10 employees.

This sentence expresses that I am the "boss" of the department and my main focus is the well being of the 10 people under me.

My best translation so far was:

> Als der Abteilungsleiter bediene ich 10 Mitarbeiter.

Meaning: I am the "boss" of the department and I had to serve 10 people in the company.

Please correct me - both in English or in German - if I made any mistakes.

Edit:

Is there a better way than the following sentence?

> Als Abteilungsleiter bin ich verantwortlich für 10 Mitarbeiter.

Comment: Look up the difference between "jemanden bedienen" und "jemandem dienen".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### jemanden bedienen

This is a wrong choice. You use this word in sentences like this:

> Der Kellner **bedient** die Gäste.
>   The waiter serves the guests.

This means: The guests are talking with each others and having fun, while the waiter is working. The waiter is bringing drinks and food to the guests.

If you say:

> Als der Abteilungsleiter bediene ich 10 Mitarbeiter.

Then you express this:

> I am the boss of the department, and as this boss it is my job to bring my employees drinks and food and to carry away used dishes.

This is probably not exactly what you did mean. (Btw: Your sentence is grammatically absolutely correct, but the meaning is weird.)

---

### für jemanden verantwortlich sein

This means »to be responsible for somebody«

> Als Abteilungsleiter bin ich verantwortlich für 10 Mitarbeiter.

This is also grammatically correct, and it has an understandable meaning. In this context it means:

> I am the boss of this department, and I have to take care for my employees. Because if some of them is doing something wrong, it will be me who gets blamed for it.

But there is even a better version:

---

### etwas leiten

> Ich leite eine Abteilung mit zehn Mitarbeitern.
>   I manage/direct a department with 10 employees.

The wording is different, because you don't manage or direct employees, but you manage a department. And the former used word »Abteilungsleiter« (i.e. »department manager« or »department director«) was split up into its components, of which one is the verb »leiten« (to guide, to manage). So there is no need to use the word »Abteilungsleiter« in this sentence.

Those sentences have the same meaning:

> Ich leite eine Abteilung.
>   Ich bin (ein) Abteilungsleiter.

Comment: For "leiten": there is also "anleiten" if you teach the employees/you help them. Then you could make the sentence: "Als Abteilungsleiter leite ich 10 Mitarbeiter an" though you might want to find a synonym for "Abteilungsleiter" because this construct sounds strange.

Comment: @A.Hue: But it is not »Abteilungs**an**leiter«. It is »Abteilungsleiter«.

Answer (score 5):

*bedienen* does not serve (sic) the purpose well here.

The *serving* role of a manager has not yet found its way into common German language yet.

You could use "führen" or "leiten"

> Als Abteilungsleiter [führe|leite] ich eine Abteilung mit 10 Mitarbeitern

or

> Als Abteilungsleiter [verantworte ich|bin ich verantwortlich für] einen Bereich mit 10 Mitarbeitern

Note you are also walking on dangerous grounds here: *bedienen* can carry a connotation of "to sexually please" in German - something you wouldn't want to transport, I guess.

Comment: :D :D No, I definitely do not want to please my employees. :D  Still I do want to express the serving role of mine.  Is there a way to do it? Is the following better: 
"Als Abteilungsleiter bin ich verantwortlich für 10 Mitarbeiter."

Comment: If you want to express the serving role: "Als Abteilungsleiter führe ich 10 Mitarbeiter" But there is no exact german translation of "As the head of the department I am serving 10 employees." with the meaning: This sentence expresses that I am the "boss" of the department and my main focus is the well being of the 10 people under me. This meaning cant be expressed in one single short german sentence.

Answer (score 1):

"Als Leiter(in) der Abteilung bin verantwortlich für 10 Mitarbeiter." is the best translation.

"verantwortlich" has two dimentions: Responsibility for what my employees are doing as well as how they are faring. It means both. You should add:

Ich unterstütze sie dabei, ihre Potenziale voll zu entwickeln.